# Error while installing the mimemagic in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am using rails 4.2.4 and try to install paperclip gem in my application. After editing my gem file when I run bundle install.Then I got the error.

```
Bundler::GemspecError: Could not read gem at /home/darkpasenger/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/cache/mimemagic-0.3.0.gem. It may be corrupted.
```

An error occurred while installing mimemagic (0.3.0), and Bundler cannot continue.

Make sure that `gem install mimemagic -v '0.3.0'` succeeds before bundling.

So I run the command `gem install mimemagic -v '0.3.0`.Then again I got the error.

```
ERROR:  Error installing mimemagic:
invalid gem: package is corrupt, exception while verifying: undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) in /home/darkpasenger/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/cache/mimemagic-0.3.0.gem
```

Please help me out to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting this file from the system

```
/home/darkpasenger/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/cache/mimemagic-0.3.0.gem
```

and then try installing the gem again. It seems that the gem was not properly downloaded.

Answer (score 40):

I found the answer here: https://programmerah.com/mimemagic-0-3-10-install-error-and-bundler-cannot-continue-26830/

but I have pasted the steps in case the link stops working.

1. brew install shared-mime-info
2. bundle install

These two commands fixed the issue for me.

fissh

Answer (score 5):

These two commands fixed the issue for me.

1. brew install shared-mime-info
2. bundle install

But i need to run first this command `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*` because `brew install shared-mime-info` is failed in my system with the error `permission denied @rb_file_s_symlink`